# MYSQL Replication _ Master port is 3306 and slave port is 3307

Tags: mysql

I have set master - slave replication.

```
Master mysql port = 3306
master server id = 1

Slave mysql port = 3307
slave server id =2
```

log-bin is enabled on master, and also replication user is
created on master with replication rights.

```
change master to
master_host = 'masterIP',
master_port=3306,
master_user = 'username',
master_password= 'password',
master_log_file = 'mysql-bin.000037',
master_log_pos = 89265280;
```

But when I run

```
Start Slave;
```

It shows error as below.

```
Error Code: 1794. Slave is not configured or failed to initialize properly. You must at least set --server-id to enable either a master or a slave.
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: on master its 5.7 and on slave its 5.6.

Comment: Hey can you try above scenario with same version of MySQL on Master and slave,

Answer (score 1):

```
Master mysql port = 3306
master server id = 1
mysql vesrion 5.5.50

Slave mysql port = 3307
slave server id =2
mysql version 5.5.50
```

I have tested the above scenario with Master port 3306 and slave 3307. And it's working fine. I have followed the steps you have given in the question.

As you have mentioned in the comment.I think it compatibility issue.You can check with the similar version.

```
 mysql master version = 5.7
 mysql slave version = 5.6
```

> Statement-based replication depends on compatibility at the SQL level between the master and slave. In others, successful SBR requires that any SQL features used be supported by both the master and the slave servers. For example, if you use a feature on the master server that is available only in MySQL 5.7 (or later), you cannot replicate to a slave that uses MySQL 5.6 (or earlier).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

Try running `SELECT @@global.server_id;` on the slave to make sure it has got the `server-id` you think it does. If not you can run `SET @@global.server_id=2;` and make sure it is set up in the `my.cnf` file for when you restart the database.

Also check the error logs as there may be additional info in there that can help.

Comment: No Its, Not working.
I can see SERVER ID = 2 when i run above query.
But still i am getting same error.

Comment: Same with me. Cannot for the life of me find an answer. I have server id set in mysql AND the my.cnf file. Still can't start slave.

Answer (score 0):

Set `server_id` in my.cnf on both servers.  `SET` is not sufficient, since it does not happen soon enough.

The Slave needs to be *newer*, not *older*, than the Master.  Else, incompatibilities may cause failures.

Comment: Yes Ofcourse,
I have set server id in my.cnf.
Server id for master and slave are different, 
I have also stopped and started Mysql server to be on safer side,But No success. So I Dont see any problem with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The slave is supposed to be on a higher version than the master not the other way around, as pointed must be a compatibility issue.

Answer (score -1):

Check the permissions on your my.cnf .